# LL component of wavelet transform

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I applied the discrete wavelet transform to an image using `dwt2` and displayed the `LL` component.  It shows a brighter image instead of a blurred image. Can anyone please tell me why it is brighter?

My code is:

```
 I=im2double(imread('lena1.jpg'));
 [LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(I,'db1');
 imshow(LL);
```

Comment: Can you link to the original image and the `LL` image you are getting? I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @eigenchris - Try using any stock image that comes with MATLAB, like `cameraman.tif`.  If you do a `dwt2` on the image, you will most likely get values that go beyond 1 if converted with `im2double`.  Simply doing `imshow(LL,[]);` should solve the problem.

Comment: @rayryeng. I see. I had entered `imshow(LL,[]);` by habit so I didn't catch the fact an image would get oversaturated.

Comment: @eigenchris - lol.  Good.  Stick with that habit!  I can assure you that at least 10 of my answers with MATLAB and image processing have `imshow(...,[]);` as the answer to get it working.  People forget that displaying images which go beyond the max value of the data type for the image will simply saturate the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because the `LL` component most likely has values that go beyond 1 since you converted with `im2double`.  When trying to display that image, try doing this instead:

```
imshow(LL, []);
```

This will map the lowest value to 0 and the highest value to 255 and scaling everything linearly in between.  Note that this **won't** change the actual `LL` variable.  `imshow` with `[]` as the second parameter will internally scale the intensities so that the values get mapped between `[0,255]` respectively.

Comment: imshow(LL,[ ]); is working but i want to use LL sub band separately for further processing  and it should be blurred image instead of a brighter image. how can i get that .

Comment: @aswani - You use the image as is.  It's being **visualized** as brighter because of saturation.  Any values beyond 1 get saturated to white and anything beyond 0 get saturated to black.  You don't need to change the image at all.  You use `LL` as is for the next step in processing.  You don't modify it because if you did, you wouldn't be able to reconstruct the original image when using the other subbands.

Comment: @aswani - I believe I have answered your question.  If you have another question, please make a new one.  Otherwise, if I have answered your question here, please consider accepting it.   That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down buttons.  Good luck!